# Determine the norm of the continuous linear operator $T:L^1[a,b] \to L^1[a,b]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

I have encountered an exercise.

> Let $K(x,y)$ be a measurable function on $[a,b]\times [a,b]$. The
> function $I:y\in [a,b] \mapsto \int_a^b |K(x,y)|\,  \text{d}x \in  [0,+\infty]$   belongs to $L^\infty [a,b]$. Define an operator $T$ by
> \begin{equation} Tf: x\in [a,b]\mapsto\int_a^b K(x,y) f(y) \, \text{d} y \in [-\infty,+\infty],
>  \qquad \forall f\in L^1[a,b]. 
> \end{equation}  Show that $T$ is a
> continuous linear operator from $L^1[a,b]$ to $L^1[a,b]$, and
> \begin{equation} \|T\| = \|I\|_\infty. \end{equation}

Clearly, by  Fubini's theorem, we can obtain
\begin{align*}
 \|Tf\|_1& = \int_a^b \left| \int_a^b K(x,y) f(y) \, \text{d}  y\right|\,  \text{d}x
  \leq \int_a^b \int_a^b \left| K(x,y) f(y)\right|\,  \text{d} y \, \text{d}x
 \\  &=\int_a^b |f(y)|\int_a^b \left| K(x,y)\right| \, \text{d}x \, \text{d} y 
 = \int_a^b |f(y) I(y)|\, \text{d} y \leq \|I\|_\infty \|f\|_1,\qquad\,  \forall f\in L^1[a,b],
 \end{align*}
thus $\|T\|\leq \|I\|_\infty$.

But I have no idea how to prove the converse inequality. Thanks.

Comment: the usual technique would be to prove $\|T\|\geq\|I\|_{\infty} - \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon > 0. $ Equivalently, you need to prescribe an $f_{\varepsilon}$ such that $\|Tf_{\varepsilon}\|_1\geq\|f_{\varepsilon}\|(\|I\|_{\infty} - \varepsilon)$

Comment: I see, thanks, dezdichado. And I'm trying  to approximate $K$ with a sequence of continuous functions.

Answer (score 1):

For these operator norm inequalities, upper bounds are easy but for lower bounds you need to demonstrate that the proposed norm is sharp (because the norm is a supremum--it's easy to bound a supremum above, but hard to bound it below in general).

So, we need to show that there are $f \in L^1[a,b]$ so that $||f||_1 = 1$ and $||Tf||_1$ gets arbitrarily close to $||I||_{\infty}.$ Wlog assume $K \geq 0$ by breaking $K$ into positive, negative parts (note that the infinity norm of $I$ is the sum of the norms of the $I^+, I^-$ functions defined by replacing $|K$| with $K^+, K^-$, which is why this works).

Fix a Lebesgue point $y$ of $I$. Define $f \in L^1[a,b]$ to be within $\epsilon$ of a Dirac mass $y.$ By letting $\epsilon\rightarrow 0,$ we find that we can get $||Tf||_1$ to essentially be $I(y).$ Varying the Lebesgue point $y$, we derive the result, since some Lebesgue points must be arbitrarily close to attaining the infinity norm.